# Return JAX-RS text/plain list as multiple lines

Tags: list, text, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using RESTEasy 3.1.0.CR3 with Tomcat, as shown in this Maven POM snippet:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have a resource that produces `text/plain` information, and returns a List, containing for example `new FooBar("foo")` and `new FooBar("bar")`. When I access this resource RESTEasy returns:

```
[foo, bar]
```

That looks suspiciously like JSON. I'd rather the list be returned as multiple lines, like this:

```
foo
bar
```

Is there an easy way to get RESTEasy to return a `text/plain` list as multiple lines rather than pseudo-JSON with comma separation? Or will I have to write a `MessageBodyWriter`?

Answer (score 1):

It is sending correct data since you are return list ,it is calling list.toSring and returning the output [foo, bar] .
If you want it in multiple line then you have to create such string and return it.

Comment: Oh! Haha --- it didn't even strike me that this was the `toString()` form of the list implementation. I was thinking it was a default provider for lists. Oh, well --- let me know if you think of an easy way around it. (I've already written a `MessageBodyWriter`, but there may be an easier way.)